# Use left alt as compose key

Tags: keyboard, keyboard-layout, compose-key

Ubuntu 16.04 only gives me the following options to use as a compose key (under System Settings > Keyboard > Typing):

- Disabled
- Right Alt
- Right Ctrl
- Right Win
- Left Ctrl
- Menu
- Caps Lock

Is there any way I could use Left Alt as my compose key (Menu is not it apparently)?

Comment: See https://askubuntu.com/questions/957513/how-can-i-set-the-compose-key-to-end/1086627#1086627 and https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2416537. I guess you can use the same steps to set the key of your choice as the compose key.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think so. XKB provides a few more options; you can view them by running this command:

```
cat /usr/share/X11/xkb/rules/evdev.lst | grep compose
```

But Left Alt is not one of them.

*Edit:*

There may be a `xmodmap` way to fix it; please see [DK Bose](https://askubuntu.com/users/248158/dk-bose)'s comments.

Comment: Please see my comment to the question. Those links may provide a general solution.

Comment: @DKBose: I edited the answer and mentioned it.