# How can I set the compose key to End?

Tags: gnome, keyboard, keyboard-layout, compose-key

**Note: I am using the Gnome desktop environment**

My laptop keyboard has only the keys it needs, and few of the normal compose keys available. I use them all.
I'd like to set the compose key to <kbd>End</kbd>, but it's not on the list in Gnome Tweak Tool:

[image]

How can I set the compose key to <kbd>End</kbd>?

Comment: AFAIK you can't do that easily. It's a limitation of XKB, which would need to be modified somehow.

Comment: @GunnarHjalmarsson According to the Arch wiki on xkb, you can use xmodmap to set keys not offered by xkb as the compose key. I'm not up to testing it out right now, but this may work for OP.

Comment: @chaskes Would I remap it to XF86Compose? Where did you see this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I solved the problem with help from [@chaskes](https://askubuntu.com/users/117123/chaskes):

```
xmodmap -e "keycode 115 = Multi_key End"
```

remapped the first level of <kbd>End</kbd> to the compose key, but allows me to press <kbd>Shift</kbd>-<kbd>End</kbd> to send an actual <kbd>End</kbd> keypress.
I made this permanent by putting it in my `~/.xinitrc`.

Other sources:
https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/109472/
https://askubuntu.com/a/24930/

Comment: Awesome. Don't forget to accept your answer once it lets you.

Comment: I will... Tomorrow.

Answer (score 2):

On my system, the *insert* key is totally useless. Touching it could only create typing errors. And the name makes sense for a Compose key.

xev told me that the *insert* key is keycode 118.

So my ~/.xmodmap is 2 lines:

```
keycode 118 = Multi_key
! Insert key is Compose key.
```

And for backup, I execute this in my startup file:

```
xmodmap -e "keycode 118 = Multi_key"
```

I don't really know if **both** changes were necessary, but it works perfectly and I don't feel like messing with it.